# VB6 and C++ boolean literals

Tags: c++, vb6

I am learning C++.  I come from a background of: .NET and VB6.

I am intrigued about what the following webpage says about booleans: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381404(v=vs.85).aspx i.e.

> "Despite this definition of TRUE, however, most functions that return a BOOL type can return any non-zero value to indicate Boolean truth. Therefore, you should always write this:

```
// Right way.
BOOL result = SomeFunctionThatReturnsBoolean();
if (result) 
{ 
    ...
}
```

> "

Does this apply to VB6 as well i.e. is there a problem saying: `If BooleanValue = True Then`?

Comment: Unfortunately, following this guideline tends to introduce a lot of warnings about implicit conversions from `int` to `bool`.

Comment: Related: [Not Logical Is VBScript](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/07/15/184431.aspx), by Eric Lippert. (The differences between VBScript and VB6 are not relevant in this particular case.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Windows API was designed to be used from C programs.  Which until C99 didn't have a *bool* type.  And still doesn't completely, C99 was never implemented by the Microsoft compiler for example.  So they had to come up with a workaround, one that's highly compatible with the way C compilers deal with logical values.  An int where 0 is false and anything else is true.  Thus the advice.

VB6 has a dedicated Boolean type and keywords for the literal values True and False so doesn't quite have the same problem.  You can however still get into trouble with poorly written COM servers.  The underlying integral value for True is -1, highly incompatible with many other languages' implementation of a logical boolean type.  Including C.  There's a good reason for VB6 being the oddball, its And and Or operators don't distinguish between a logical and a arithmetic and/or.  By making True equal to -1 and False equal to 0 there is no difference.  Trouble can arise when a COM server returns a 1 to indicate true instead of VARIANT_TRUE.

But most of all, writing `If booleanVariable = True Then` is just ugly and nails on the blackboard for many programmers.  Just write `If booleanVariable Then` and be done with it.

Comment: +1, nails it. Good explanation of the technical background, too.

Comment: Hans, Could you explain why writing: "If booleanVariable = True Then" is ugly? Also, if the COM server never returns an integer for a boolean value i.e. always returns a literal i.e. TRUE or FALSE, then there shoud not be a problem, right? The VB6 COM component is used by VB6 clients only.  Thank you.

Comment: Because is is superfluous.  There's just no point in writing code that doesn't need to be there to make it work.  COM servers are typically written in C++.  It has the *true* literal but it has the wrong value, thus the problem.  Clearly there's no issue at all if the server is implemented in VB6.

Answer (score 2):

Not in VB, no, as `True`/`False` are real boolean values.  In C/C++ however, `BOOL` is just a #define of `int`, thus you can assign a BOOL variable any integer value (`TRUE` in C is a #define of 1 (usually) and `FALSE` a #define of 0).

If you want better overlap with your VB experience, use the `bool` datatype in C++ which uses actual `true`/`false` values.

EDIT: Of course, in VB you say `If BooleanValue = TRUE`. In C++, the equivalent is `if (BooleanValue == true)` (note the *==*, which is a comparison operator, as opposed to *=* which is an assignment operator), but in C++ you can skip the `== true` comparison and just use `if (BooleanValue)`.

Comment: Just to clarify my "usually" statement: I've seen some projects where it uses `#define FALSE 0` and then `#define TRUE !FALSE`.

Comment: Nick, In the article, it says do not use If BooleanValue == True? In your answer, you say that If BooleanValue = True in VB6 is the equivalent of writing If BooleanValue == True in C++.  Also could you clarify what you mean by a #define on 1? Does this mean that that a value of 2 would return false? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if you do `if (BooleanValue == TRUE)` and BooleanValue was actually 2, that would fail, hence why the article recommends using `if (BooleanValue)` instead.

Comment: you CAN have a Boolean value that is not the same value as `True` or `False`. It's difficult to do, but is possible, which is one of the reasons that you shouldn't do `= True`.

Comment: @Deanna: How so? Would be interested to know.  I suppose an uninitialized variable could technically be defined as neither value, but is there another way?...

Comment: You can get garbage values when reading from a file (it's still a 32-bit value...) CopyMemory(), coming from an API (that uses 0,1), etc.

Comment: Ah yes, good point, copying memory directly in would indeed do random and bizarre things.